How can I customize the name of log files that are created by logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler in python?
I am using this configuration for my logging system.
logging.config.dictConfig(
    {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "formatters": {
            "format": {"format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"}
        },
        "handlers": {
            "console": {
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "formatter": "format",
                "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
            },
            "file": {
                "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
                "filename": "data/logs/main.log",
                "mode": "a",
                "formatter": "format",
                "maxBytes": 1024 * 1024,
                "backupCount": 100,
            },
        },
        "root": {"handlers": ["console", "file"], "level": "DEBUG"},
    }
)

this configuration makes 11 log files for my project with these names:

main.log
main.log.1
main.log.2

...

main.log.99
main.log.100

I want these names to be something like these:

main.log
main-00.log
main-01.log

...

main-98.log
main-99.log

How can I do this customization on the name of log files?
Another problem is that main-36.log may have the newest logs and so main-37.log has the oldest logs.
I want when the size of main.log reaches the maxBytes all of the log files to shift one (

main-01.log copy to main-00.log
main-02.log copy to main-01.log

...

main-98.log copy to main-97.log
main-99.log copy to main-98.log

) and after that main.log copy on last file (main-99.log).
in this order, main-99.log always has the newest logs and main-00.log always has the oldest logs
How can I do these?

thanks to @sahasrara62 and @Vinay for their answers.
first of all, I noticed that shifting stuff happened in the logging system and needed no change at all.
then for renaming log files created by logging, I combined those two answers so I used the namer function and also created a custom class based on logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler that overwritten the doRollover function, and the result was something like this example.
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os


def namer(name):
    return name + ".log"

def get_number_of_digits(value):
    return len(str(value))

class CustomRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler):
    def doRollover(self) -> None:
        if self.stream:
            self.stream.close()
            self.stream = None
        number_of_digits = get_number_of_digits(self.backupCount)
        if self.backupCount > 0:
            for i in range(self.backupCount - 1, 0, -1):
                sfn = self.rotation_filename(
                    f"{self.baseFilename[:-5 - number_of_digits]}-{i:0{number_of_digits}}"
                )
                dfn = self.rotation_filename(
                    f"{self.baseFilename[:-5 - number_of_digits]}-{i + 1:0{number_of_digits}}"
                )
                if os.path.exists(sfn):
                    if os.path.exists(dfn):
                        os.remove(dfn)
                    os.rename(sfn, dfn)
            dfn = self.rotation_filename(
                f"{self.baseFilename[:-5 - number_of_digits]}-{"0" * (number_of_digits - 1)}1"
            )
            if os.path.exists(dfn):
                os.remove(dfn)
            self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
        if not self.delay:
            self.stream = self._open()

FILE_NAME = "logs"
BACKUP_COUNT = 10
NUMBER_OF_DIGITS = get_number_of_digits(BACKUP_COUNT)
FIRST_LOG_FILE_NAME = f"{FILE_NAME}-{"0" * NUMBER_OF_DIGITS}.log"
CRFH = CustomRotatingFileHandler(FIRST_LOG_FILE_NAME, maxBytes=1024, backupCount=BACKUP_COUNT)
CRFH.namer = namer
CRFH.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(message)s"))
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(CRFH)

for i in range(1000):
    logger.warning(f"Log number: {i + 1}")


In this example if we set the variable FILE_NAME to logs and set the BACKUP_COUNT variable to 10 then the logs save into files like these:

logs-00.log
logs-01.log
logs-02.log

...

logs-08.log
logs-09.log
logs-10.log

So it makes 11 files that, file number 0 (logs-00.log) always has the newest logs, and file number 10 (logs-10.log) always has the oldest logs.

Use the namer attribute as described in the official documentation here and here.

you need to create a custom handler based on RotatingFileHandler
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


class CustomLoggingHandler(RotatingFileHandler):
    # do all customization here

handler = CustomLoggingHandler(filename, mode='a', maxBytes=0, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, errors=None)

you need to modify the input to this customhandler according to your needs. this is just default value taken from documentation
then add this handler to logging module as
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(handler) # <- custom handler which is created

and then use this logger object to log things which you want
